# Writing my own system call to count how many o's appear in string pointer

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

So I've been tasked to write my own system call in linux. This system call will take a pointer to a character array and replace all o's with 0's. The system call will return the number of replacements performed. If the string size of larger than 128 bytes, it will return -1. So I've already implemented a different system call that works completely fine following the steps in this link. 
https://medium.com/anubhav-shrimal/adding-a-hello-world-system-call-to-linux-kernel-dad32875872 . I have double checked everything and everything seems fine, so I believe it is something wrong in either my system call that I wrote or when I test it. Assuming this is the case, is there anything wrong with my system call? I think it may have something to do with the character pointer or something of that sort.

Here is my system call.

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>

asmlinkage int sys_my_syscall2(char * string){
    if(sizeof(string) > 128){
        return -1;
    }
    int x, count = 0;
    for(x = 0; x < sizeof(string); x++){
        if(string[x] == 'o'){
            string[x] = '0';
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Here is my test file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {
    int syscall2 = syscall(333, "Hello World");
    printf("Syscall 333 printed %d", syscall2); 
    return 0;
}
```

333 is the number of my syscall. After running the test file, it pauses for an extremely large time and seems to freeze. Even after trying to control-C, the program still seems to run. Is there a problem with these files?

Comment: `sizeof(string)` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: You are passing a const string to a system call that will modify your memory.  Did you try using a writable memory buffer?

Comment: You have three problems: The first is that `sizeof` of a pointer gives the size of the *pointer* and not what it points to. The second problem is that the data (the string) you want to iterate over is in user-space and needs to be copied to kernel-space (though this I'm not sure about). The third problem is that literal strings are ***read-only*** arrays of characters, you can't modify them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way is to:

- Pass pointer to string to the syscall
- do a `strlen_user(string)` to find out the size of the string
- Provide a buffer large enough to hold the string (for example with `kmalloc()`)
- use `copy_from_user()` to copy the string from userspace into a kernel buffer (check if the call succeeded!)
- Perform the substitution operation on the kernel buffer
- use `copy_to_user()` to copy the string back to userspace
- Free the buffer if you allocated one with `kmalloc()`.

You should not access userspace directly, since the kernel may oops if the memory pointed to by your pointer is not available (i.e. swapped out) or protected for read/write. This is for example the case in your program; trying to write to this memory directly (without copy_to_user) will result in a kernel page fault. **Note :** Direct access *can* work, but it is *not* safe!

Furthermore, you have to use `strlen(string)` (or `strlen(string)+1` to account for the terminating zero byte) when operating with strings.